# How to reference a component's props in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that can accept another component as a prop. Whatever other props it has, it also passes them down to the child component. That's what it looks like:

```
interface FormGroupProps extends BasicInputProps<any> {
  label: string
  name: string
  Component: ComponentType<BasicInputProps<any>>
}

export const FormGroup: SFC<FormGroupProps> = ({
  label,
  Component,
  ...props
}) => (
  <RBSFormGroup>
    <Label>{label}</Label>
    <Component {...props} />
  </RBSFormGroup>
)
```

You can see that in `FormGroupProps` I tell TS that Component will accept only props of a certain type. That is not ideal, because sometimes I need to pass components that don't necessarily match that signature.

I could potentially just write `ComponentType<any>`, but that's too loose. I'd like to be able to write something like `ComponentType<Component['props']>`, but as far as I know there's no such thing.

Is there a way to reference a components props type? Or do I need to pass a generic type manually to achieve that?

Comment: a bit confused, didn't get what types of component do you want to accept

Comment: Interesting.  The only thing I can think of to try is the new-ish `React.ComponentProps<typeof Component>`, although expecting it to work for a generic item might be asking too much.

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii I want to accept all types of components, but be able to restrict props only to the props of that component

Comment: @DylanWalker it works! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Didn't think it'd be quite powerful enough for this specific case, but nice to have some confirmation to the contrary :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New typings introduced to `@types/react` in response to React 16.6 include the following types:

```js
type ComponentProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | JSXElementConstructor<any>> =
    T extends JSXElementConstructor<infer P>
        ? P
        : T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
            ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]
            : {};

type ComponentPropsWithRef<T extends ElementType> =
    T extends ComponentClass<infer P>
        ? PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<InstanceType<T>>
        : PropsWithRef<ComponentProps<T>>;

type ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T extends ElementType> = PropsWithoutRef<ComponentProps<T>>;
```

Which reference the types of a component's props.  You should be able to achieve your desired interface using one of these new types:

```js
interface FormGroupProps {
    label: string;
    name: string;
    Component: React.ComponentProps<typeof Component>;
}
```

This is super handy if you want to avoid exporting prop interfaces all over the place, or for extracting props interfaces from libraries which don't export them.  Also, unlike `Component['props']`, it also works for functional components.